# How do I force print_r() to only print a few bytes of data?

Tags: php

I try to find out whats inside $item in the following example:

```
foreach ($address->getAllItems() as $item) {
    Mage::Log("item: ". print_r($item, true), 7, "model.log");
    exit();
}
```

However, it is way too big and I get `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted`. I already set the memory_limit to 1024 in php.ini

Is there a way to only print a rather small portion, e.g. only the first 128 MB?

Comment: I found that `var_dump()` works better than `print_r()` when inspecting objects that might recurse.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, nice, with `var_dump()` it it is showing :) But I wonder if there is actually a way to limit it to X bytes e.g. for servers with smaller RAM.

Comment: Is it that 1 $item is causing a problem or the number of items?

Comment: I'm quite certain there is no means to limit it by amount of memory. I do seem to recall seeing somewhere an argument or setting to limit recursion, but I can not find it now.

Comment: @NigelRen, I think the 1 $item, because I set an exit() it can only show one.

Comment: what data are you trying to view? I find that `get_class_methods` helps select a function that you actually want to see, then just print_r that

Comment: You could try using `json_encode()` which allows you to limit the depth.

Answer (score 0):

If $item is a string, you could just cut it in pieces of length 100:

```
foreach ($address->getAllItems() as $item) {
    for ($i=100; $i<strlen($item); $i+=100) {
        $shortItem = substr($item, $i-100, $i);
        Mage::Log("item: ". print_r($shortItem, true), 7, "model.log");
    }

    $shortItem = substr($item, $i-100, strlen($item));
    Mage::Log("item: ". print_r($shortItem, true), 7, "model.log");
    exit();
}
```